# First 255 of long text into a Text field

Tags: custom-field, long-text-area

I'm looking for a way to take the first 255 characters of a long text field and plop it into a text field.  Is there a formula field or workflow rule solution?  Or am I going to need to loop through characters in a trigger?

Comment: [LEFT](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#LEFT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use workflow field update to do this, `TRIM(LEFT( Description , 255))`
You can replace the description with the field you wanted to copy from.

Comment: Would this need to be in a workflow rule?  I tried this in the formula field type field and it says the long type field could not be used

Comment: yes, you should put in in a workflow field update

Comment: haha :) How can any one use the Long Text Area Field in Formula Field. I don't think it is possible in any manner. @AnuragA, Please edit the answer according to the Workflow Rule which will answer the question correctly....

Answer (score -1):

You can use formula field to display first 255 characters of long text field.

```
 IF(LEN(Custom_description__c)>255, LEFT(Custom_description__c,255),LEFT(Custom_description__c, LEN(Custom_description__c)))
```

Comment: Your formula goes the long way around to get the value of Custom_Description__c if not > 255. ex, this should be fine `IF(LEN(Custom_description__c)>255, LEFT(Custom_description__c,255),Custom_description__c)` even so still not very concise.

Comment: Don't think this is possible - long text fields aren't available in formula fields so `Custom_description__c` wouldn't be accessible.